# Is there any open source folder/browser/creator for Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

We are looking to create a document management area that models a standard folder structure using Azure blob storage in an MVC3 applicaiton.

E.g.

1. Users can create folders
2. User can upload documents to folders
3. Users can list directory contents etc
4. Users can delete documents
5. Users can download documents

Now I appreciate Azure Blob storage only has containers and the rest is faked by slashes creating paths. However this sort of functionality seems like the sort of thing someone else must have created?

I did some searching but coultn't find anything. Basically something like CloudXplorer or Azure Storage Explorer but web based

Does anyone know of any azure blob storage implementation with web front end (ideally MVC)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start looking at [BlobShare](http://blobshare.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Get%20Started), an MVC application which allows you to upload, download, view, share, ... blobs:

[image]

However, for the sorting part you'll need to build something yourself. I would personally consider using the Windows Azure Caching (Preview) to do this; whenever you access a 'directory', cache the blobs in that 'directory' and do the sorting based on the data in teh cache (same applies to paging). And use something like Service Bus Topics / Queues to refresh the cache whenever someone adds/deletes/renames/... a blob (+ timeout for directories not accessed in X minutes).

Answer (score 0):

I also found this sample. http://peterkellner.net/2010/11/12/azure-storage-treeviewer-directory-browser/. It isn't web based but seems to create a basic tree structure and displays  it. There is also related discussion here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredata/thread/256cfc0f-bccc-4bf7-b7eb-cb7c7aca0c8a

Answer (score 0):

See my answer over here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65944680/7988162 on how to use the Storage Explorer across all platforms.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question unless you can call into the core functionality of Storage Explorer from MVC? This is about a web layer over the top of the storage

Answer (score 0):

Hierarchical blob storage now exists through Data Lake Storage Gen2. Check out documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview).