# Azure storage for files in specific folder structure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

Currently i have some ftp where on it i have some deep structure of folders and files within it. It could be even 10 levels down from root folder. As i migrated already with success my local database to azure database, i wonder also whether is there any azure ftp i could use to migrate this as well. I know we have something like Azure storage and i could create Container for it of type File or Blobs - are one of those could be used like particural ftp - could i create folder structure there somehow using container and either File or Blob for that purpose, how it works there? Does either container blob or file for such purposes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me add to what NDJ has written. So both Azure Blobs and Files would serve your purpose.

As mentioned by NDJ, Azure Blob Storage is a 2-level hierarchy system. At the top you have a blob container and the each blob container contains 0 or more files. So it does not support a folder structure per se but as NDJ mentioned, you can create an illusion of a sub folder by using appropriate blob delimiters (usually `/`). If you were to compare it with local file system, a directory at the root level (C:) is a container in blob storage and then the files would go in there. So imagine you have a folder called `images` in C:\ of your computer, that would be a container in blob storage. Now imagine that you have 2 sub folders beneath this folder (let's call them `hires` and `lores`) and both of them contains some files (say `image1.png`). When you move them to Azure Blob Storage, the container name would be `images` but the blob names would be `hires/image1.png` and `lores/image1.png`. Some of the storage explorers would take this delimiter (`/`) and show you that your container contains 2 folders and inside each folder you have an image called image1.png but in reality there are only 2 blobs in that blob container.

Azure File Service is a close match to your local file system. At the top level, you've got a `Share` and each share will container directories and files. Each directory can again contain many directories and files.

As NDJ mentioned, there's no FTP access to Azure Storage but there are many tools that will allow you to upload files from local computer to Azure Storage and many of them will preserve the file hierarchy. You can always write code to upload the files yourself. If you decide to use Azure Files, you can simply mount a File Storage Share as a network drive on your local computer and then transfer the files from your local computer to Azure Files as if you're transferring files from one drive to another.

**UPDATE**

Regarding difference between Azure Blob Storage and File Storage, both are used to store files. There are a few differences that I could think of:

- A `Share` in Azure File Storage can be mount as a network drive on your local computer/Azure VM whereas a `Blob Container` in Azure Blob Storage can't. So if you have an application which writes files to local file system, you can take the application as is and make use of Azure File Storage and write the file to that network drive without making many changes to your code (typical example of `Lift-And-Shift` kind of application.
- You can set `ACL` on a `Blob Container` whereas you can't do the same on a `Share`. This makes Azure Blob Storage ideal for storing static content (images, css, js) for your websites. For exposing files in File Storage, you would need to resort to `Shared Access Signature`.
- You can set the size of a `Share` (default is 5GB) whereas no such thing exist for a `Blob Container`. A blob container can go up to the size of a storage account.

To understand Azure Files, I would recommend reading this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/.

Comment: i still can't get difference between file and blob storage could you give one more example? I thought file is like ftp.

Answer (score 4):

Azure blob supports 10 levels down (up to [254](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135715.aspx).  Basically the files are stored non hierarchically, but each / separator gives the appearance of directories.
It's relatively trivial to write something to move files to azure, as far as I know there is no ftp functionality yet - but it has been [requested](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/397724-allow-to-upload-data-to-azure-blobs-by-a-classic-f).  It looks like some people have already [created some code for this](http://ftp2azure.codeplex.com/)

Comment: so if there is possibility to have container and up to 256 folders down why you said there is some workaround code for it, or i still missing something here? Is container in fact a folder, and blobs subfolders or?

Comment: in reality it's all flat, but if you put a file up to the container called "A/B/C/file.txt', azure explorer, etc. show it in a directory structure (i.e. you drill into A, B, C to get "file.txt".)  You can traverse the directories in code, as you can on the local file system.

Comment: i ahve to more question and will mark as answer: 1) so container its more like a folder which could store files (up to 256) is it all correct? 2) Creator always ask me either for container of blob/or file so does it mean either container blob is folder for blobs files and container of type file for?? 3) What in case i create like you said file A/B/C/file.txt - how ftp clients like winscp will trade is as file.txt which is placed within folder hierarchy or?

Comment: The container is like the root directory, to which you can add 254 layers deep, I think there is 200 TB limit of actual files.  You have one container, and files are hierarchical within it from their name.  A "directory" can only exist if it has files within it.  You can check whether an entry is a directory or file - CloudBlobContainer.GetDirectoryReference(path).ListBlobs().Where(t => t is CloudBlobDirectory);  The best suggestion I have is just to try it out, put some files up and have a play...

Answer (score 0):

You can now use [Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) across all platforms to easily work within any folder structure.